# Why doesn't CSS Display none!important working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I make display none from developer tool, it works.

[image: from developer tool]

**But doesn't work when I write CSS.**

[image: from developer tool]

Can anyone explain why `display:none!important` isn't working?

Here is how I tried... http://cssdeck.com/labs/ykhhehvv

Comment: styles in a parent document don't effect elements in an iframe

Comment: no css is getting applied to it. check in jsfiddle

Comment: You are trying to apply css to iframe content from parent page. It will not apply.

Comment: @XenioGracias - if it were, then the MailChimp branding would be hidden and the OP wouldn't have a question

Comment: I guess the lesson is, if you're going to use a free service like Mailchimp, you can't hide the fact that you're using a free service like Mailchimp by hiding their "branding" - it's probably against their T&C's and AUP's to do so anyway

Comment: Does the element exists in an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying css to the page which is at mailchimp server not at your localhost.And both are not same.So it will be not affected actually. If you will try in developer tool, it will work but in real it will not affected.